# Self health check for Hidden Service

Tags: network-health, systemd

I've found that my hidden service occasionally becomes unreachable. Restarting TOR on the server helps. I want to remediate the connectivity issue automatically. To know when to restart, I need a reliable health check. I'm running an HTTP server, so a simple `curl` to the own onion address seems to be a good health check. Now, it shouldn't be too hard to develop a `systemd` script.

I want to check if others ran into this issue and if there are existing solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named checkifisonline.sh  (give it permission read and write) allow Executable ) working in ubuntu or whonix or in tails drag and Drop in the terminal and hit enter ..

*remember to change the onion site in the script for yours.. and to put the path to the music .mp3 ..

script here
https://anonfiles.com/P6KeU475p4/checkifisonline_txt

When the Site will go down The alarm will start .. Take note in ubuntu if the alarm start and the site is ok .. restart ubuntu start the script again .. how i do ?

in ubuntu i have tor installed .. i start in the terminal tor

cd tor-browser_en-US/

./start-tor-browser.desktop

i do that is start tor After i open a terminal

i start anonsurf (working in ubuntu )

i do
sudo anonsurf Start

after i open a terminal in the folder Where i have put the script and the .mp3 music i drag and drop the script and hit Enter if Tor is open the script will working after less of 4 min i see The site is UP .. when is go down is Write in red the site is Down and the music Start !

take note tor was under ddos attack Junuary 2021 .. They will patch That next tor Version probably !

https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/issues/40237

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with following:

RendPostPeriod N (I set it on 20 minutes)
(seconds|minutes|hours|days|weeks)
Every time the specified period elapses, Tor uploads any rendezvous service descriptors to the directory servers. This information is also uploaded whenever it changes. (Default: 1 hour)

HiddenServiceNumIntroductionPoints NUM (I set to 7)

Number of introduction points the hidden service will have. You can’t have more than 10. (Default: 3)

And I also set to crontab a script that sends SIGHUP to tor service every 4 hours.